# How to read $A=[0,1]\times[a,5]$

Tags: geometry, notation

I have this problem: consider the two sets $A$ and $B$

$$A=[0,1]\times [a,5]$$ and $$B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$$

What are the values of $a$ that guarantee the existence of a hyperplane that separates $A$ from $B$.

Given a chosen value of $a$, find one of those hyperplanes.

My main problem is axiomatics: how do I read: $A=[0,1]\times[a,5]$, what's with the $\times$?

Thank you

Comment: Note that geometrically $[0,1]\times [a,5]$ is a *rectangle*.

Answer (score 5):

$[0,1]\times[a,5]$ is the Cartesian product of the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[a,5]$:

$$[0,1]\times[a,5]=\big\{(x,y):0\le x\le 1\text{ and }a\le y\le 5\big\}\;.$$

More generally, for any sets $A$ and $B$,

$$A\times B=\big\{(a,b):a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\big\}\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

The $\times$ stands for cartesian product, i.e. $X\times Y=\{(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$. 
Whether ordered pairs $(x,y)$ are considered a basic notion or are themselves defined (e.g. as Kurtowsky pairs) usually does not matter. See alo [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair).